# Bedroom over garage with shallow roof with no insulation with temperature problems

Tags: insulation

There is a similar question on here "What can I do about a room over the garage with temperature problems?"  I certainly found some help in that thread as to correcting the cold floor.

However; I believe there are more to my problem.  The roof over our bedroom is a shallow pitch that is tongue and grove on the inside with no insulation.  There are six beams that carry the load of the roof exposed inside the room.  With no insulation currently in the ceiling, any heating is not being trapped in the room.

I'd like to use a spray foam on the tongue and grove joints to help seal any leaks.  Once that is done, I'll need to building structure between the beams.  They are 3' wide cavities and 10" in depth.  I was thinking about using 2X8"s as the structure for the insulation.  Allowing the bottom of the beams to remain exposed to the room.

I could get you the actual void dimensions if that helps. Vertical or horizontal insulation is still a question I have.

Beyond that, per the other question, I need to pull the ceiling the garage in order to remove the existing insulation.  Hire someone to come in and spray foam the joists with a high density cellulose.

Thank you

Comment: Pictures would help a great deal here

Comment: What's the actual question? And if a related question is pertinent, please provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing rigid foam insulation panels. It would be much simpler and easier than creating an entire framed structure to contain and cover traditional insulation batts. Combined with foam at the joints as mentioned, you could get a pretty decent insulation value.

Comment: If I did that without the framed structure, how would I put up the ceiling to cover the rigid foam?